# Test Class for PostinstallScript

Tags: apex, unit-test

I am receiving an error :

> 'Error: Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature:
>   Test.testInstall(PostInstallClass, NULL) at line 5 column 7'

for the below test class.

Code:

```
@isTest
public class testInstaller{
    public void testPostInstallClass() {
        PostInstallClass postinstall = new PostInstallClass();
        Test.testInstall(postinstall ,null);
        Test.testInstall(postinstall, new Version(1,0), true);
    }
}
```

class:

```
 global class PostInstallClass implements InstallHandler {
   global void onInstall(InstallContext context) {
// If installing for the first time, setup data.
    if (context.previousVersion() == null) {
    // load Static Resource containing JSON and to deserialize it and save as records.
        StaticResource someObjectStaticResource = [select Body from StaticResource where Name = 'PocSFTF_CustomSet__c'];
        List<PocSFTF__SFTFPOC__c> someObjects = (List<PocSFTF__SFTFPOC__c>) JSON.deserialize(someObjectStaticResource.Body.toString(), List<PocSFTF__SFTFPOC__c>.class);
        insert someObjects ; 

        StaticResource HistoricD= [select Body from StaticResource where Name = 'PocSFTF_HistoricData__c'];
        List<PocSFTF__SFTF_Historic_data__c> HistData= (List<PocSFTF__SFTF_Historic_data__c>) JSON.deserialize(HistoricD.Body.toString(), List<PocSFTF__SFTF_Historic_data__c>.class);
        insert HistData;
    }
}
}
```

Kindly help me with this issue.

Comment: Can you check API version of the class saved? That has been added recently, so ensure that there is new api version for apex class (like 37)

Comment: @kurunve Its 37

Answer (score 1):

I managed to reproduce this by using a class that does not implement `InstallHandler`.

Make sure that your `PostInstallClass` is explicitly implementing it:

```
public class PostInstallClass extends InstallHandler {
    public void OnInstall (InstallContext context)
    {
        // do stuff here...
    }
}
```

The `extends InstallHandler` part is key here

Edit: after your answers, I see that the class implements the right interface. I have been unable to reproduce your error. At this point I would try this:

- Add the `@isTest` annotation to your method
- Comment out the failing line and see if the next line fails as well. It could be a case of the Apex compiler not being able to assign a type to that `null` value.
- Swap the lines around
- Extract a variable (`Version myVersion = null;`) and supply it to the `Test.testInstall` method.

Answer (score 1):

Many times when a custom Apex Class "Test" is created, you might see this problem since standard System.Test class is hidden by custom apex class "Test".

Try to replace lines

```
    Test.testInstall(postinstall ,null);
    Test.testInstall(postinstall, new Version(1,0), true);
```

with

```
    System.Test.testInstall(postinstall ,null);
    System.Test.testInstall(postinstall, new Version(1,0), true);
```

If issue is resolved then you have the problem described. Try to search for "Test" unmanaged class in your organization.